# change node.js installation directory

Tags: node.js

I downloaded the windows msi of node.js v5.6.0 64bit. When I execute it, it popped up a warning "Invalid E: drive" and shut down.  There is no way to change the installation drive. I don't have E: drive, instead I want to install to an external drive F:.  I think there was a previous installation on E: drive when my external drive was set as E.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled Nose.js. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me. Locate

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Node.js`

There you will find an `InstallPath` property. Rename the drive to whatever valid drive on your system, then reinstall and install node again.

Comment: Good job! Amazing!

Comment: Want to transfer a bounty from mine.

Answer (score 9):

Open a Command Prompt and run:

```
subst E: C:/
```

Then if you would prefer to install it to drive F: select that drive during the NodeJS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about Windows and registry, not about NodeJS. Here's the fix:

> - Important: The following steps require you to modify the Windows
>     registry. Modifications to the Windows registry, if not done
>     correctly, can cause serious problems to a Windows system. Be sure to
>     backup your registry before making changes.
> - Choose **Start > Run**. The Run dialog box opens.
> - In the **Open** field, type **regedit** and then click OK. The Windows Registry Editor opens.
>     In the Registry Editor, locate the following registry key:
>     `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
> - In the right pane, note the values in the **Data** column of each
>     entry. If any value contains a drive that is not correct for your
>     computer, right-click the entry and select **Modify**.
> - Type the correct drive letter in the **Value data** field, and then click OK. For example,
>     if one of the values is "X:\Documents and Settings\Administrator", the
>     drive letter should be changed to a valid drive on the system, such as
>     “C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator".
> - Repeat step 4 for each entry whose Data value contains an incorrect drive. Repeat steps 3
>     through 5 for each of the following registry keys:
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
>
> - Close the Registry Editor, and run the installation again

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327763

Comment: I found nothing in those keys that contains invalid drive letter. All I could fine are c:/... which is valid drive.  However, I found some keys contain %USERPROFILE% which also points to c:\...

Answer (score 0):

I partitioned my drive and made a E: partition, doing this removed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just create partition D:\ in disk management... Win + R / diskmgmt.msc
and let you install it