# Can not use or uninstall Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using windows and installed Node.js a while ago and I now can not use it or uninstall it as it is on drive D:\ which is no longer with me. I have looked at the windows regedit solution but could not find anything of use in there.

Comment: Can't you not install it in drive C: again?

Comment: No because when I go to install/uninstall it just says invalid drive D:\

Comment: take a look at nvm for windows: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: I need to use node.js to run a script though :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you go to re-install Node.js from the windows install package, the installer asks you where you want the install to be placed. Right now, I'm assuming you are presented with D:[some directory]. there should be a button located directly below the textbox showing the current install path. click that and pick a new location for your install. For instance mine is set to C:\nodejs.

> EDIT

Check your environment variables for any paths that reference D:\ in association to Node and remove them

Comment: I can not even get to that screen though https://i.imgur.com/05c4Pzk.png

Comment: what is the "windows regedit" solution you mentioned? Do you have a link for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451598/change-node-js-installation-directory the first answer

Answer (score 11):

go to registry editor-->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->SOFTWARE and delete nodejs

Comment: This fixed my Issue.

Comment: In my case it was installed on a disk that no longer existed, disk E, the files were in D, I did not need to remove just changed the location of the installation on that same path. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to Window +r then enter command regedit and go to registry editor-->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->software and change instalPath then uninstall and install again node js

Answer (score 0):

go to registry editor >HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software and delete the folder